# rotate Leptonica Pix

Tags: android, tesseract, leptonica

I am using tesseract-android-tools api. 
I need to rotate image as a pix before calling tesseract for result.
I try to use

```
Rotate.rotate(Pix pixs, float degrees, boolean quality)
```

After saving rotated image, I can see that just the content has been rotated.
See the add images.
What I did is also set the Rect with correct dimensions, but no result  :

```
rect = pix.getRect();
Pix p = Rotate.rotate(pix, 90, true);
int tempBo = rect.right;
rect.right = rect.bottom;
rect.bottom = tempBo;
api.clear();
api.setImage(p);
api.setRectangle(rect);
```

or creating new Pix, with correct dimensions, also no result  :

```
Pix temp = Pix.createFromPix(pix.getData(), rect.right, rect.bottom, pix.getDepth());
```

Any Idea how to rotate correctly image on pix level?

[image: Image need to be rotate]

[image: after calling Rotate.rotate(..) , rotate just content]